# HyperLink problem

Tags: c#

i want to add ?orderBy=countryasc to my current url. I try with Request.Url but does not working i always get http://viamura.si&orderBy=countryasc instead http://viamura.si?search=something&orderBy=countryasc

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlCountryUp" runat="server" NavigateUrl="&orderBy=countryasc">U</asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: It is nice to accept answers and give you that warn fuzzy feeling of helping others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NavigateUrl simply defines what string will go into the href="" attribute of the anchor tag in this case, the rendered HTML looks like:

```
<a href="&orderBy=countryasc">
```

Since the URL doesn't begin with a protocol string (`http://` or `https://`) it's assuming it's a relative link from the current file. You'll need to include the name of the current file as well.

Also, you can get the URL of the current file, with all parameters passeed to it, by using: `<a href="<%= Request.RawUrl %>&orderBy=countryasc">`. It looks like something along this line is what you were looking for. Make sure that you know for certain that orderby=countryasc will never be the first parameter on the querystring though -- parameters must be separate from filename by "?" so that has to be the first delimiter.

Comment: Hi Paul. Yes this is what i was looking for. It look likes that HyperLink has big problems when you want to create dynamic link
http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/5364.aspx

Thx

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the name of the page you want to link.  For instance if you are at `default.aspx?id=1` then you need to include that in the `NavigateURL`.  It will not append query string parameters to what you originally had in the URL.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlCountryUp" runat="server" NavigateUrl="default.aspx?id=1&orderBy=countryasc">U</asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: hmm ?search=something is dynamic so is not always word something. 

I try like this
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlCountryUp" runat="server" NavigateUrl="?query=<%#Eval(Request.Url.ToString()) %>&orderBy=countryasc">U</asp:HyperLink>

but is not ok.

Comment: What is your page's URL? Is this in using asp.net webforms or MVC?